# mPDF ignoring Paragraph <p> align Center

Tags: html, mpdf

i create a PDF using mPDF version 5.5.
The HTML includes a table with this HTML code:

```
<tr>
    <td width="184">
        <p dir="RTL" align="center"><strong>Programming</strong></p>
    </td>
    <td width="378">
        <p dir="RTL" align="center"><strong>No Cost</strong></p>
    </td>
</tr>
```

The HTML seems to look fine when i show it but when printing to PDF, the mPDF ignores the **align="center"** and aligning it to the left.

How can i make the align="center" work in mPDF?

Comment: can you show us more of your code ?

Comment: Have you tried using up-to-date (non-90's) code `style="text-align: center;"`?

Comment: @Justinas - yes i tried it but it didn't have effect

Comment: @ Jishnu - it is a table code:<div align="right">
<table style="width: 562px;" dir="rtl" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td width="184">
<p dir="RTL" align="center"><strong>Hello</strong></p>
</td>
<td width="378">
<p dir="RTL" align="center"><strong>MyText</strong></p>
<p dir="RTL" align="center"><strong>TempText</strong></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="184">
<p dir="RTL" align="center"><strong>anothertext</strong></p>
</td>
<td width="378">
<p dir="RTL" align="center"><strong>More Text</strong></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="184">  and so on...

Comment: i forgot to mention, the centering doesn't work only for paragraphs inside table cell - centering text in cells

Answer (score 1):

> "Block elements (e.g. DIV or P) are not supported inside tables. The content is displayed, but any CSS properties which apply to block elements are ignored (e.g. borders, padding, margins etc)."

Source: https://mpdf.github.io/about-mpdf/limitations.html

Answer (score 0):

It would work if you used css instead of the `align` attribute. instead select that element in css and use the css property: `text-align: center;` Maybe use inline css: `<p style="background-color: red;">Hello</p>`

Comment: I'm sorry but it didn't work too. i don't have access to css from the HTML Editor i use (before passing to mPDF). as i said above, in the editor it looks as centered already (without the css). it's just when i use mPDF to create the PDF, the center aligning inside table cells doesn't work. i also updated to 6.0 version. it doesnt work still.

Comment: Use inline css then @Rodniko

Answer (score 0):

You can set a different alignment for inner table element by wrapping content in another table

```html
<tr>
  <td style="text-align: center;">
    Centered
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td style="text-align: left;">Aligned left</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </td>
```